# Selenium in docker container WebDriverException: Message: connection refused

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, docker

I am doing POC with selenium+python+firefox, soon I have to test the same with chrome.

Please refer my github: https://github.com/jauyzed/selenium-firefox-python

FYI: I have not committed all the required files

When I run the container, I see the following errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/selenium_wd_tests/google_test_ff.py", line 10, in setUp
  self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/distpackages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 145, in __init__
keep_alive=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 92, in __init__
 self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 179, in start_session
response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, capabilities)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 236, in execute
self.error_handler.check_response(response)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 192, in check_response
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
WebDriverException: Message: connection refused
```

Found a few OP's here but none had answers.

Any thoughts anyone?

Comment: Have you configured your docker container's internet connection with DNS?

Comment: @sytech I have internet working inside the container.

Comment: check this `https://windsooon.github.io/2017/06/14/How%20to%20use%20selenium%20with%20docker/`